how to works woocommerce cart hash
I have a WordPress store and I built it using the WooCommerce plugin. Today, I encountered an issue with my site that I need help resolving. The problem is as follows:
Imagine a scenario where a logged-in user adds a few products to their cart. Two days later, they return to my site but unknowingly log out. They then add another product to their cart, but suddenly realize that they are not logged in. They then proceed to log in to their account, but upon doing so, their new cart overwrites their previous cart.
I found my issue, I wrote a plugin for login and register, and I understand this issue appeared for this plugin, I used the wp_set_current_user function for logged-in users please see this function and say where is my problem
my code is:
add_action('wp_ajax_SubmitPass', 'SubmitPass');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_SubmitPass', 'SubmitPass');
function SubmitPass()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $UserID = intval($_POST['UserID']);
    $UserPass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['UserPass']);
    $User = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `user_pass` FROM `wp_users` WHERE `ID` = $UserID");
    $UserPassHash = $User[0]->user_pass;
    if (wp_check_password($UserPass, $UserPassHash, $UserID)) {
        wp_set_current_user($UserID); // Set the current user detail
        wp_set_auth_cookie($UserID); // Set auth details in cookie
        if (get_user_meta($UserID, 'UserPhone', true) == '') {
            echo 'GoToGivePhone';
        } else {
            echo 'OK';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'incorrect';
    }
    die(0);
}


The issue probably isn't directly related to your custom login code (what is the purpose of that supposed to be in the first place here anyway?) If you logged in the "normal" way, wp_set_current_user would also get called in the process. "but upon doing so, their new cart overwrites their previous cart" - you would need to find the place where their previous cart is supposed to get restored, and then merge the "new" cart and the existing one somehow.

FYI, if the user's password contained <, >, " or ', I would expect your login attempt there to fail to begin with. (Unless you gave the password the same inappropriate treatment at the time of user registration.)

I found the answer to my problem and I am posting it here so that it might help someone, You should put the following two lines after the wp_set_auth_cookie function:
wc_update_user_last_active($UserID);
update_user_meta($UserID, '_woocommerce_load_saved_cart_after_login', 1);

The problem is solved that easily.
